# Getting name of table columns in gridview in addition to custom names

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a simple grid on my ASPX page and I am binding it with data coming from a select query on button click event. I am not sure how to bind columns of this table with my grid as currently I am getting 8 columns, 4 with the header given in aspx page and 4 with headers of table columns. Below is my button click event code.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyBookListCont myBookListCont = new MyBookListCont();
            gdvMyBooks.DataSource = myBookListCont.SearchBookDetailsCont();
            gdvMyBooks.DataBind();            
        }
```

And below is aspx code of gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdvMyBooks" runat="server">
    <Columns>            
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BK_NM" HeaderText="Book Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ATHR_NM" HeaderText="Author Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BUY_YR" HeaderText="Buy Year" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PRICE" HeaderText="Price" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Looks like a silly question, but help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have explicitly specified 4 columns in this design code :

```
<Columns>            
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BK_NM" HeaderText="Book Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ATHR_NM" HeaderText="Author Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BUY_YR" HeaderText="Buy Year" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PRICE" HeaderText="Price" />
    </Columns>
```

Now here, as you can see, there is a `HeaderText` property which will override the table column name and display the text that is mentioned in here.

You have a couple of options here that you can try :

First, if you want all columns like this with custom header text, you can define all the other columns with these 4 in the same manner as well. That will display all the data and column headers as per the given format.Something like this :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gdvMyBooks" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server">
    <Columns>            
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BK_NM" HeaderText="Book Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ATHR_NM" HeaderText="Author Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BUY_YR" HeaderText="Buy Year" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PRICE" HeaderText="Price" />
        //other columns using same syntax as above.
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Also, if you dont want to bind all columns coming in your query, you can use this attibute in your gridview,

```
AutoGenerateColumns = False
```

And just specify the columns that you need like you have currently done.

The other thing is, if you want to straight away bind the result in your query to your `GridView`, then just remove those 4 `BoundField` statements and leave as it is. This will bind your table to `GridView` with the same header names as the column names.

I hope this makes things clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your `GridView.AutoGenerateColumns` to false :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdvMyBooks" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

Otherwise, it will bind all the field of your object.